# Mongoose can find related documents with lookup but not populate

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a simple Mongo DB with two models: Campaign and Donation, where a Campaign is related to many Donations.

Using mongoose I can query for a specific Campaign using an aggregation with a `lookup()` and it returns all of the related Donations. But if I try to use a `populate()` statement, no Donations are returned. I cannot figure out why.

**Campaign**

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;
require('models/Donation');

const CampaignSchema = new Schema({
  name: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  goal: {
    type: Number,
    required: true
  },
  donations: [{
    type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: "Donation"
  }]
}, 
{ 
    collection: 'campaigns'
});

mongoose.model('Campaign', CampaignSchema);
```

**Donation**

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;
require('models/Campaign');

const DonationSchema = new Schema({
    campaign: {
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: "Campaign",
        required: true
      },
      amount: {
        type: Number,
        required: true
      },
      date: {
        type: Date,
        required: true,
        default: Date.now
      }
}, 
{ 
    collection: 'donations'
});

mongoose.model('Donation', DonationSchema);
```

This code will return a single Campaign based on _id and all of the associated donations:

```
const filter = {_id: mongoose.Types.ObjectId(req.params.id)};
Campaign.aggregate().match(filter).lookup({
  from: "donations",
  localField: "_id",
  foreignField: "campaign",
  as: "donations"}).then((results) => {
    console.log(results[0].donations); // HAS ALL OF THE RELATED RECORDS
});
```

This code returns an empty array for donations:

```
const filter = {_id: mongoose.Types.ObjectId(req.params.id)};
const campaign = await Campaign.findOne(filter).populate('donations').then((c) =>{
  console.log(c.donations); // EMPTY
});
```

Comment: What tells Mongoose that it should join on the `campaign_id` field? (I honestly don't know, but suspect that's the difference and problem here). Maybe this: https://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html#populate-virtuals

Comment: Oops, sorry. You are correct. I had the `campaign_id` in there from a previous attempt. I've edited the question.

Comment: I reworked my schema to include the virtual like you mentioned and it worked! If you turn that into an answer I can mark it.

Comment: Can you post the code where you create a new `Campaign`?